# Why can I have a const char pointer point to a mutable char array?

Tags: c, string, pointers, constants, string-constant

Why is this fine:

```
char a[2];
a[0] = 'a';
const char *b;
b = a;
printf("%s\n", b);
a[0] = 'b';
printf("%s", b);
```

why can a pointer to a constant string point to a non constant string? Also how do string constants work when assigning them to variables? Why can you do this:

```
const char *b = "hello";
b ="test";
```

or

```
char *b = "hello";
b = "test";
```

but you can only do the first line if it is an array? constant or not?

Comment: *"why can a pointer to a constant string point to a non constant string?"* Why not? The opposite would be dangerous, yes, so it's not allowed without a cast. `const char* b="hello";` You can't modify strings literals (it causes UB), but they are not constant in the sense that their type has no `const` in it.

Comment: `const char *b` means you can't change the string contents through `b`, but you can still reassign `b`. To make `b` constant you have to write `const char * const b`

Answer (score 5):

> Why can I have a `const char *` point to a mutable `char` array?

The `const` here below with `b` puts a *restriction* on its use.  It is not allowing some new usage, but potentially less.  So no opening of [Pandora's Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandora%27s_box) here.

```
char a[2];
const char* b = a;
```

`b` has read-access to the array.  The array `a[]` may still change via `a`.

```
a[0]='y'; // OK
b[0]='z'; // leads to error like "error: assignment of read-only location "
```

> Also how do string constants work when assigning them to variables? constant or not?

`"hello"` is a *string literal* of type `char [6]`.  With the `const char* b1 = "hello"` declaration and initialization, `b1` is assigned a pointer of type `char *`.  This could have been `const char *`, yet for historical reasons<sup>1</sup> it is `char *`.  Since it is `char*`, `char* b2 = "hello";` is also OK.

```
const char* b1 = "hello";
char* b2 = "hello";
```

> Also how do string constants work when assigning them to variables?

```
b="test";
```

As part of the assignment, the *string literal*, a `char` array, is converted to the address and type of its first element, a `char *`.  That pointer is assigned to `b`.

---

<sup>1</sup> `const` was not available in early C, so to not break existing code bases, *string literals* remained without a `const`.

Comment: If what you say is true, then sizeof ("hello") == 6?  If that is the case, then today I re-learned that C never ceases to surprise me.  Just when you think you know something...

Comment: However, isn't it also true that modifying a string literal in C is undefined behavior?  That is, `char *b = "hello"; strcpy(b, "world");` leads to undefined behavior?  Maybe that's why I've got it in my head that "hello" is a `const char*` type.

Comment: @jdc Yes, True.  It is good to think of a _string literal_ as a `const char` array even though it does not have that `const`-ness in it type, just in its application.

Comment: @jdc Now a little secret: `((char *)b)[0]='z';` is OK.  It is OK to cast away `const`-ness and use that pointer `(char *)b` to write **if** the array pointed to is not `const` (and not a _string literal_), as in OP's case.  Yet casting away `const`-ness can lead to UB in other cases, so wise to avoid.  Oh, I see [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60328496/why-can-i-have-a-const-char-pointer-point-to-a-mutable-char-array/60328919#comment106717973_60328834) has that.

Comment: That's another good point my answer failed to address - distinguishing between variables declared as `const` versus treating a non-`const` type as `const` inside a function.  Since there is no portable way to distinguish between a `const` variable versus treating one as `const` in a function, I would avoid casting it away (or, send out a department-wide email letting my coworkers know where I live when that assumption is violated ;))

Comment: @jdc "Since there is no portable way to distinguish between a const variable versus treating one as const in a function" --> Hmmm, It is not  variable `const`-ness, but the `const`-ness of what it points to this post discusses.  With that, I think one _can_ distinguish with `_Generic`, yet that is a whole new question with various caveats.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add const-ness to a type. This is a *good* thing, because it allows you to write functions that make some guarantees.

```
//Here we know *str is const, so the function will not change what's being pointed to.
int strlength(const char *str) {
    int length = 0;
    while (*str++)
        ++length;
    return length;
}

int main(void) {
    char a[2] = "a"; //a[0] and a[1] are mutable in main(), but not in strlength().
    printf("%d", strlength(a));
}
```

Note that casting away const-ness leads to undefined behavior:

```
void capitalize(char *str) {
    if (isalpha(*str))
        *str = toupper(*str);
}

int main(void) {
    const char *b = "hello";
    capitalize((char*) b); //undefined behavior. Note: without the cast, this may not compile.
}
```

As for your second question, your first example is correct because the type of a string literal in C (i.e. any sequence of characters between double quotes) is of type `const char*`.  This is valid:

```
const char *b = "hello"; //"hello" is of type const char*
b = "text"; //"text" is of type const char*
```

Because casting away const leads to undefined behavior, this code is invalid:

```
char *b = "hello"; //undefined behavior; "hello" is const char*
b = "text"; //undefined behavior; "text" is const char*
```

The case for arrays is a little more involved.  When used in expressions, arrays act as pointers, but arrays are a fundamentally different type than pointers:

```
char a[10];
a = "hello"; //does not compile - "hello" is a const char*; a is a char[10]
```

However, when used in an initialization statement, the rules state that a `const char*` can be used to initialize a character array:

```
char a[10] = "hello"; //initialization - a is a char[10], "hello" is a const char*
                      //a will contain {'h','e','l','l','o',0,0,0,0,0}
```

Also, don't forget that you can assign a string literal to an array with strcpy:

```
char a[10];
strcpy(a, "hello");
assert(strcmp(a, "hello") == 0);
//a will contain {'h','e','l','l','o',0,x,x,x,x}
//here x's mean uninitialized
```

Comment: In C, passing a pointer to a `const`-qualified type is not a guarantee it will not be changed. It is an advisory and a convenience (because the compiler will warn if an attempt to modify is made with a `const`-qualified lvalue). If the pointed-to object was not defined with `const`, a `const` pointer to it may be converted to a non-`const` pointer and used to modify it.

Comment: I agree with you that it is not a guarantee it will not be changed, but casting away const even inside the function that accepts a pointer to a const-qualified type still leads to undefined behavior.  With undefined behavior, doing anything or nothing at all would not violate the standard.

Comment: No, casting away `const` and using it to access an object that was not originally defined with `const` has defined behavior. The part of the C standard that makes attempting to modify an object defined with `const` not defined by the standard is C 2018 6.7.3 7: “If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined…” There is no similar text for objects not defined with `const`, except for string literals. This is because const was grafted onto C late, so it is a bit of a kludge.

Comment: Thank you for the reference.  Still, when I write C, I look at casting away `const` inside a function as a red flag, and would try to avoid it if possible.  There really is no good way around it in the case of `strchr`.